# How do I get brightness controls working properly on an Eee PC 1001P?

Tags: 12.04, brightness, eeepc

Is there a solution to the low screen brightness issue with the Eee PC 1001P and release 12.04?

When I use the brightness control, the screen goes through three adjustment cycles of dark to semi bright, but never gets to bright. As you index the control up, brightness increases, then suddenly cuts back to dark. use the brightness button to further increase the brightness and the same cycle happens. As though there are three distinct brightness events, each one setting back to low level. Under no circumstances other than initial boot up can you get to a bright screen. I just finished installing 12.04 on two Acer (Gateway netbooks) with no brightness issue. Just on the Eee PC 1001P

Eee PC model is 1001P

Comment: Brightness control works great with Xubuntu 12.04 on my eee PC 901 and 1000H. It's somewhat non-linear, but will go from dark to bright. Maybe try `acpi_backlight` on the kernel command line?

Answer (score 0):

[These instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EeePC/1001P#Screen_Brightness) might help, [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/512567) being the relevant bug.